# Overlaping sounds with push of ImageButton

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

I am making an app that plays sound that a user chooses. first they select the category, then they choose a specific sound. the sounds are not very long, currently the app will play sounds just fine. however if the user selects one sound and then they select a second sound to play the 2 sounds will overlap(the beta testers find this annoying apparently). I have tried both media player and sound pool. After researching the issue I discovered that the likely cause of the overlap is that I use `mp = mediaplayer.create(this,raw.soundfile); mp.start()` to play each sound. I have since tried to alter how the sound in played. After reading several posts including [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm) below is the relevant code I currently have

```
public class [classname] implements [something] extends[somethingelse]{
    MediaPlayer mp; //moved out of play sound method

        protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          mp = new MediaPlayer();// added to this area
        }
        public void playSound (View view) {

           if (mp.isPlaying() ){
              mp.stop();
              mp.release();
           }   
           switch (selection) {
                            case "sound1":
                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
                                mp.start();
                                break;
                            case "sound2":
                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
                                mp.start();
                                break;
                            case "sound3":
                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound3);
                                mp.start();
                                break; 
    **10 more cases in this playsound method**
```

After some trial and error and help from Udi Idan the above code is what is currently working in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the overlapping, you should check weather a sound is playing and stop it:

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
    mp.pause();
```

And then play the new sound.

**Edit**

You should be consistent with the way you play the sound.

Create one MediaPlayer variable as class member:

```
MediaPlayer mp;

if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
}

switch (selection) {
                    case "sound1":
                       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
                       mp.start();
                       break;
                    case "sound2":
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
                        mp.start();
                        break;
                    case "sound3":
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
                        mp.start();
                        break; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, sadly it did not solve the problem. When just adding `mp.pause();` didn't help I also added `mp.release();`. Still overlapping the sounds- my above code has been edited to reflect this try.

Comment: Why are you loading each sound in a different way? in this example you should only use mp, otherwise why will the sound stop? If you play sound3 using sounder and sound1 using mp?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I was trying to show what I had already tried and messed up with the comment sections. I have edited the above to better reflect what my actual code looks like and the sounds still overlap. The if (mp !=null && mp.isPlaying() ){...} doesn't do anything

Comment: Create MediaPlayer mp;  as a class member (not inside the method)

Comment: Thank You!! it is working great now. Slight alteration(shown in edited above code) to the if block and that too is working as it should.

Comment: Great :)  just one note, you shouldn't instantiate the MediaPlayer in onCreate, just add a check for NULL when you attempt to stop it:
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
}